# retrieve interest rates for credit cards using Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

I am using Yodlee to get the transactional history and summary of accounts for my clients to do some predictive maths on their debt levels.

Is it possible to get the interest rate for a credit card account? Looking in the data model [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Card_Account) there are references to APR and interest paid to date.

However using Testdrive These fields are not being returned using: getItemSummaryForItem1 or getContentServiceInfo1.

The banks I am using are ANZ (NZ) and ASB (NZ) I would like to know if these sites do not support credit card interest rates, if they do please let me know what api calls I need to make to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a data field interest rate(APR) is supported, but it also depends upon the bank whether they provides it or not. If you are existing Yodlee customer, you can send a request to Yodlee Support team to get your doubts clarified. BTW, the API should be used- [getItemSummariesForSite](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummariesForSite) or [getItemSummaryForItem1](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummaryForItem1)( if you are looking for further details, pass correct Data Extents, while making request).